# REACT NATIVE - How to call Fast Refresh in code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, asyncstorage

My app has a save feature that uses AsyncStorage but whenever I save data, I need to refresh the app to see the changes. The Fast Refresh feature in my Expo is working great. but what I actually want is to use Fast Refresh in my code so that whenever I save data my app will automatically Fast Refresh itself. Is that possible?

Comment: Fast refresh without changing your code is basically just rerendering the component. If you add code it will be clearer why you need to refresh to see the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao try to re-render the component by using `this.forceUpdate()` in this way:

```
someMethod() {
  // Force a render without state change...
  this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Anyway, you could avoid this by putting a state var in render function and chenge it when you want to re-render component. It's easier and more compliant to react logic.

For more info check [here](https://davidwalsh.name/react-force-render).